# Show that the order of $G$ cannot be divisible by $7$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutations

Show that the order of a proper primitive group of degree $19$ cannot be divisible by $7$.

It means as following-

This means that a group $G$ which acts on a set $\Omega$ of cardinality $19$ (this is what degree means) and action is transitive and primitive  , and proper means that when we see its permutation representation, $\phi :G \to S_{19}$ then $\phi(G) \neq A_{19}$ or $S_{19}$.

For the solution of this, If i let $7 ||G|$, then there will be a sylow $7$ subgroup , say, $P$, now if I can show, as per hint in the book, that $C_G(P)$ contains a $5$- cycle, then obviously, $P=1$ and I am done, but how to show $C_G(P)$ contains a $5$- cycle?

Comment: $\phi(G)\ne S_{19}$ does not mean not faithful for faithful means that means $\ker\phi=1$ (and is part of the definition of primitive group, I suppose)

Comment: sorry, i edited that, but proper here does  mean that $\phi(G) \neq S_{19}$

Comment: The alternating group of degree $19$ is primitive, properly contained in $S_{19}$, and has order divisible by $7$ (twice!).  Are you sure "proper" doesn't mean something else, or that you are not missing some other assumption?

Comment: Ohh then I must be having the wrong notion of proper here, It is the statement, I don't know what else it means.

Comment: Maybe it means "not symmetric or alternating"?  Those seem to be the only two primitive (=transitive) groups of degree $19$ with order divisible by $7$.

Comment: @James I guess you are right, but if some one could say for sure and explain why. thanks

Comment: @James you were right. Found it in Dixon's book on page 59. Thanks editing it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't make any sense at all of your comment "if $C_G(P)$ contains a $5$-cycle then obviously $P=1$". You are trying to prove that $A_n \le G$.

There is an old result of Jordan that says that, if a primitive permutation group $G \le S_n$ contains a $p$-cycle with $p<n-2$, then $A_n \le G$, and I am guessing that you are expected to use that.

So, if $G \le S_{19}$ is primitive and $G$ contains a $7$-cycle, then $A_{19} \le G$ and we are done, so assume not. Then, assuming that $7$ divides $|G|$, all elements of order $7$ in $G$ consist of $2$ disjoint $7$-cycles, and a Sylow $7$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ has order $7$ and fixes exactly $5$ points.

There is a general result that the normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ in a transitive permutation group acts transitively on the fixed points of $P$. It's proof is an easy application of Sylow's Theorem.

Using that, $N_G(P)$ acts transitively on the $5$ fixed points of $P$, so $5$ divides $|N_G(P)|$ and there exists $g \in N_G(P)$ of order $5$. Now since $5$ does not divide $|{\rm Aut}(P)|=6$, $g \in C_G(P)$. Clearly $g$ must fix both of the $2$ orbits of $P$ of size $7$, and hence it must fix all points of both orbits. So $g$ is a $5$-cycle and $A_n \le G$ by Jordan's Theorem.

Comment: ohh sorry, you are right, it don't make much sense, the way i wrote. I meant If we let $P$ be any non trivial sylow $7$ subgroup, then showing a $5$ cycle in $C_G(P)$ ,it will contradict that $P$ is non trivial.And  so $7$ wont divide order of $G$

Comment: $A_{19} \le G$ does not tell me that $|G|$ is not divisible by $7$. Rather then it will be for sure. How does this help?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - you are trying to prove that, if $G$ is a primitive group of degree $19$ and order divisible by $7$, then $A_{19} \le G$.

Comment: Ohk. You doing the contrapositive of what I asked. same thing. Fine. Thanks for this approach.

Comment: Just one doubt, why $P$ has order $7$ (and not $7^2$). There are enough disjoint $7$ cycles, and also $49 | 19!$.

Comment: If $P$ had order $7^2$, then it would contain a $7$-cycle and then Jordan's Theorem implies $A_{19} \le G$.

Comment: why a $7$ cycle, it must be any element of order $7$ as per cauchy's theorem, and there are plenty of them. I am sorry if I am missing something silly here!!

Comment: A subgroup of $S_{19}$ of order $7^2$ is a Sylow $7$-subgroup, so it clearly contains a $7$-cycle.